# Why is the app name displayed in "about" Menu different than App name? (Electron, MacOS)?

Tags: macos, electron, info.plist, electron-forge

I'm using `electron-forge`, and have my app building, bundling, and running well, so I'm in the customize and polish state (set app icon, name etc).

I was able to set the `.app` bundle name, and the name displayed in the top-level menu, but for some reason, the `package.json` `name` field is still being applied in two areas (see image below). I opened the app bundle to look at the `Info.plist`, but did not see any instances of `'omni-desktop-test'`.

What setting am I missing to target these values?

[image: Example issue]

Relevant part of my forge config:

```
packagerConfig: {
    name: 'Keystone Omni',
    productName: 'Keystone Omni',
    executableName: 'Keystone Omni Desktop',
    icon: 'assets/app.icns',
    appBundleId: 'com.xxxxxxx.omni',
    appCategoryType: 'public.app-category.developer-tools',
    extendInfo: 'static/info.plist',
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While testing and attempting to make a bug report to `electron-forge`, I discovered the following:

1. The `productName` that is referred to here: https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/master/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#name is intended to be in the `package.json` file, not in the `electron-packager` config. I had not seen *'productName'* as a value in package.json before.

> The application name. If omitted, it will use the *'productName'* or *'name'* value from the nearest package.json.

2. Even if you set *'name'* in the `electron-packager` config, it will still read the `package.json`'s *'productName'* value (or *'name'* value, if not defined), for the text in the problem areas.

So the answer is, if you want this set at the bundler level:

> Use *'name'* in the packager config to set the top-level display name, and *'productName'* (or *'name'* as a fallback) in the `package.json` to set the sub-menu about, hide, quit, etc items.

Comment: As such, I've submitted a bug to the repository: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/1774

Answer (score 5):

In your electron `Main.js` file, use [`app.setName`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetnamename) to change your app's name:

```js
app.setName('Keystone Omni');
```

Comment: Tested, and this does work, but I wanted to be able to set it at build time, not run time.

Comment: @mix3d Then you can change the `name` field in yout package.json

Comment: @ViniciusBazanella See my self-answer further below that details the issue with that approach. Yes that works, but WHY it works is a problem, and in direct conflict with the documentation.

Comment: I have an app with an ampersand & in the application name.  The & is not rendered in the app menus.  Using this and setting && in the name fixed this very annoying problem...not noticed double ampersand rendering anywhere else.